# Best replacement for broken in-wall dehumidifier?

Tags: walls, basement, dehumidifier

My wife and I are new owners of a home with a partially finished basement of about 1,700 square feet. We found a dehumidifier mounted in a wood cutout in the wall near one end of the finished part. It appears to be an old Hampton Bays that exhausts out the front and intakes from its rear end from a small adjoining office. From the unit there is a hose leading through some cutouts in the wood paneling, where it drains. Here are pictures of the front, back and a closeup of the attached hose:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I believe it is no longer functioning because the humidity stays stuck near 70% regardless of whether it is running.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a similar unit on the market today. I don't see any that intake from the rear and exhaust through the front.

Portables seem to be very popular today, but the drain here appears to be high on the wall. I wouldn't be able to drain with gravity and would either have to run a pump or empty the drain manually.

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Update:

We have central air cooling. Our first zone includes the basement and first floor.

Comment: That looks like a portable that's just been fitted in-wall

Comment: What kind of HVAC system do you have?

Comment: We have central air cooling. Our first zone includes the basement and first floor.

Comment: So this is a portable? It seems to be unique in that it exhausts out the front and intakes from the back. Most portables I see on the market today do not exhaust and intake in opposite directions -- usually it's intake from the front, exhaust from the top or side. With such a narrow space here, wouldn't I need to get one with the same exhaust pattern? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: There are lots of non-portable dehumidifiers that can be controlled by an external/remote humidstat, can be ducted, and are compatible with condensate pumps. What exactly are the constraints you are trying to meet?

Comment: A "whole home dehumidifier" or "central dehumidifier" is what you need.